# No totalTime property when streaming mp3s over RTMP (Amazon CloudFront)?

Tags: flash, streaming, mp3, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

I'm building a Flash mp3 player to handle streaming mp3s served by Amazon CloudFront (which uses Flash Media Server). I'm using an FLVPlayback 2.5 component to do most of the heavy lifting (I tried an all AS3 method, but any stream automatically stopped within 5 - 10 seconds of playing). When I trace out the FLVPlayback's `totalTime` property, I get `NaN`. This is causing the seek bar to simply not work. This only seems to affect mp3s, as when I load an FLV I get a real value for `totalTime`. Does anyone know why this is happening, and if there are any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more research, I found that there's no clean solution to this problem. Adobe acknowledges the problem exists, but there's no real fix. The `totalTime` property is read/write, so I'm just going to manually set it for each song.

I should note that it may be possible to use server side Actionscript to determine the duration of an mp3 (using a `Stream` object), but as of right now, CloudFront does not support server side Actionscript.

Hopefully Adobe remedies this, or I'll be looking at other streaming servers the next time this issue pops up.